# mysql is not starting in XAMPP LINUX MINT 18.3

Tags: mysql, xampp, linux-mint

i am using linux mint 18.3 
mysql server is starting in xampp.

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.1.25-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...already running.
istiaq@istiaq-B250M-HD3 ~ $ /opt/lampp/bin/mysqld_safe_helper: Can't create/write to file '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/istiaq-B250M-HD3.err' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
/opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server: 260: kill: No such process
```

after i use :

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

then again :

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

But problem is not solved !!

Comment: Looks like you have a file system permission issue, doesn't it? You will have to check the file permissions, we cannot do that for you.

Comment: I will never understand why people use something like `xampp` on a Linux based system. You have all components installed with only a few mouse clicks anyway in your software management and they are perfectly integrated into your Linux distribution. Unlike `xampp` which is _not_ integrated into your distribution and only installs the components again which are available anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It is clearly a permission issue

try giving permission to aforamentioned folder

first you need to find out os user which my sql uses. for this you need to check

```
vi /etc/mysqld/mysql.ini
```

First Try This.

```
chown -R <mysqluser> /opt/lampp/var/mysql
```

If it does not work try

```
chmod 750 /opt/lampp/var/mysql/istiaq-B250M-HD3.err
```

if the error message changes after the last command then

```
chmod 750 /opt/lampp/var/mysql
```

or last way (not advised)

chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/var/mysql